# Can't access mysql from command line on a Mac

Tags: mysql, terminal

MySQL on OS x 10.6 is located in `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`.

I get command not found when I type `mysql --version` in the terminal. Is this because the socket path is wrong? If so how do I fix it?

Comment: comnand not found means it's not in your path. If it was a socket problem, you'd get "unable to connect" or something similar

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577374/mysql-command-not-found)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Mysql in the command line in osx - command not found?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554818/using-mysql-in-the-command-line-in-osx-command-not-found)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Just do the following in your terminal:

`echo $PATH`

If your given path is not in that string, you have to add it like this: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/` or `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin`

Comment: I tried doing both. When i echo $PATH it still says -bash: /Users/minsalaco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/Users/minsalaco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin:/Users/minsalaco/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/Users/minsalaco/.rvm/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin: No such file or directory

Comment: i removed MAMP and just want to use mysql from the command line

Comment: Please read my answer once again. I just told you how to fix your issue. `/usr/local/`is missing in your path. Just add it as explained.

Comment: Please echo $PATH again after doing the above example.

Comment: This works only temperary. if you use command + T to open a new tab. mysql is not in the $PATH anymore.

Comment: Well, then you have to add the line to your `.profile` or `.bashrc`. Not sure about the exact file that's being used.

Answer (score 26):

I'm using OS X 10.10, open the shell, type

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

it works temporary.if you use Command+T to open a new tab ,mysql command will not work anymore.

We need to create a .bash_profile file to make it work each time you open a new tab.

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

add the following line to the file.

```
# Set architecture flags
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
# Ensure user-installed binaries take precedence
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
# Load .bashrc if it exists
test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

Save the file, then open a new shell tab, it works like a charm..

by the way, why not try https://github.com/dbcli/mycli

```
pip install -U mycli
```

it's a tool way better than the mysqlcli..
A command line client for MySQL that can do auto-completion and syntax highlighting

Comment: it would be worth mentioning that path to `/mysql/bin` folder may differ and it's best to see for yourself where it is on your computer. Then change above commands accordingly.

Comment: Nice tool! I am SICK of MySQL Workbench, and have issues getting `mysql` working at the command line on my MacBook - this worked right off the bat. Love the auto-completion!

Comment: My `mysql` command line tool on mac worked like a slacker. It only worked after I added `export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"` in the `.bash_profile` file.

Answer (score 8):

On OSX 10.11, you can `sudo nano /etc/paths` and add the path(s) you want here, one per line. Way simpler than figuring which of `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, '~/.bash_profile` etc... you should add to. Besides, why export and append $PATH to itself when you can just go and modify PATH directly...?

Answer (score 7):

On mac, open the terminal and type:

`cd /usr/local/mysql/bin`

then type:

`./mysql -u root -p`

It will ask you for the mysql root password. Enter your password and use mysql database in the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried all the solutions from the answers but couldn't get `mysql` command to work from the terminal, always getting the message

```
bash: command not found
```

The solution is to change the .bash_profile, and **add the mysql path to .bash_profile**

To do so follow these steps:
1. Open a new Terminal window or make sure you are in the home directory
2. Open .bash_profile using

```
nano .bash_profile
```

3. Add the following command to add the mysql path

```
PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

4. Press **Ctrl+X**, then press y and press enter.

The following is how my .bash_profile looks like
[image]

Answer (score 0):

adding this code to my .profile worked for me:
:/usr/local/mysql/bin

Thanks.

P.S This .profile is located in your user/ path. Its a hidden file so you will have to get to it either by a command in Terminal or using an html editor.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simpler approach:

1. Install mySQL-Shell package from mySQL site
2. Run mysqlsh (should be added to your path by default after install)
3. Connect to your database server like so: MySQL JS > \connect --mysql [username]@[endpoint/server]:3306
4. Switch to SQL Mode by typing "\sql" in your prompt
5. The console should print out the following to let you know you are good to go:

Switching to SQL mode... commands end with `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run:

```bash
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql --user=root -p
```