# MySQL command line '-bash command not found'

Tags: mysql, macos, bash, phpmyadmin

The following link at the end of the post was helpful, but can someone clarify this? There are two answers that are in complete conflict, so I am asking about it.

One person responds that you should get to the MySQL command line like this.

Navigate to the directory

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

And at a Unix prompt, type:

```
./mysql
```

Then type the following to reset the password.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

But then another person says:

> No, you should run mysql -u root -p in bash, not at the MySQL command-line. If you are in mysql, you can exit by typing exit.

Neither of these work for me.

First method. From the Bash prompt:

```
mysql -u root -p

Enter password:  xxxx
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Second method from the *mysql>* prompt:

```
mysql> -u root -p
    ->
```

I also often get this error:

> -bash command not found

I am unable to log in to [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin).

My problem is that I am getting this error message when trying to log in to phpMyAdmin:

> Login without a password is forbidden by configuration

The link that I have is referenced above. Responses from 2013:

*[ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'db'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838777/error-1044-42000-access-denied-for-user-localhost-to-database-db)*

Comment: These are the first sentences of instructions "On Unix, use the following procedure to reset the password for all MySQL root accounts. The instructions assume that you will start the server so that it runs using the Unix login account that you normally use for running the server".   Start the server.  Which server ?  The apache server ?  I just open terminal and apache is running anyway that is unless I one apachectl stop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [can't access mysql from command line mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195418/cant-access-mysql-from-command-line-mac)

Answer (score 51):

To use the command, i.e., `mysql` on a [MacBook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro) terminal, you need to export the path using:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

Considering the default installation, use the following command to get the `mysql` prompt as the *root* user:

```
mysql -u root
```

Otherwise you are using the wrong root password.

Reference: *[Setting the MySQL root user password on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474775/setting-the-mysql-root-user-password-on-osx)*

Comment: Thankyou Panther.  I had gotten past that problem but today logged on about something else.  I am keeping your above posted suggestions.  They seem very logical of course :)

Comment: The above can solve the -13 error from child_process.spawn in node as well.
(I had added what I thought was needed in the path... it worked for my login but did not work for node).

Answer (score 7):

For a *permanent solution* -

1. `echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile`
2. `. ~/.bash_profile`

Refer to details at [this link](http://www.gigoblog.com/2011/03/13/add-mysql-to-terminal-shell-in-mac-os-x/).

Answer (score 1):

You can permanently add PATH to your *[~/.bash_profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)* file by the following. This will save you to run the *export* command every time you reopen the console or terminal.

1. Open the *~/.bash_profile* file using

   ```
   sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
   ```
2. Add the following line there

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
   ```
3. Save and exit the file and refresh the *~/.bash_profile* file

   ```
   source ~/.bash_profile
   ```
4. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it is connected, but you might give it a try. It could be that you simply need MySQL on your local computer.

On your computer, run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Then you will get rid of such an error. I am not sure whether it is one of the errors you mean in the title "MySQL command line '-bash command not found'":

```
/home/.../some_bash_script.sh: line 123: mysql: command not found
```

With some luck, other errors that you get are connected to this. At least in my case, I got rid of a few other errors with this step, like [ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673530/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-111/70302540?noredirect=1#comment124276076_70302540).