# Using MySQL in the command line in OS X - command not found?

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm trying to get MySQL up and running on my Mac OS X 10.9.5.

I've installed the latest version `5.6.21` of MySQL Community Server. I've gone to system preferences and started the mysql server, then launched terminal and typed this:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql --version
```

which should return the version. But when I type any of the mysql commands I get `command not found`.

I've also tried:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
mysql -u root --password=password`
```

I do have web hosting with MySQL etc installed, but I want to be able to get to grips with it in the command line first.

Comment: What's in your `$PATH`?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

So there are few places where terminal looks for commands. This places are stored in your `$PATH` variable. Think of it as a global variable where terminal iterates over to look up for any command. This are usually binaries look how /bin folder is usually referenced.

`/bin` folder has lots of executable files inside it. Turns out this are command. This different folder locations are stored inside one Global variable i.e. `$PATH` separated by `:`

Now usually programs upon installation takes care of updating `PATH` & telling your terminal that hey i can be all commands inside my `bin` folder.

Turns out MySql doesn't do it upon install so we manually have to do it.

We do it by following command,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

If you break it down, `export` is self explanatory. Think of it as an assignment. So `export` a variable `PATH` with value old `$PATH` concat with new `bin` i.e. `/usr/local/mysql/bin`

This way after executing it all the commands inside `/usr/local/mysql/bin` are available to us.

There is a small catch here. Think of one terminal window as one instance of program and maybe something like `$PATH` is class variable ( maybe ). Note this is pure assumption. So upon close we lose the new assignment. And if we reopen terminal we won't have access to our command again because last when we exported, it was stored in primary memory which is volatile.

Now we need to have our mysql binaries exported every-time we use terminal. So we have to persist concat in our path.

You might be aware that our terminal using something called [`dotfiles`](https://dotfiles.github.io/) to load configuration on terminal initialisation. I like to think of it's as sets of thing passed to constructer every-time a new instance of terminal is created ( Again an assumption but close to what it might be doing ).  So yes by now you get the point what we are going todo.

`.bash_profile` is one of the primary known `dotfile`.

So in following command,

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

What we are doing is saving result of `echo` i.e. output string to ~/.bash_profile

So now as we noted above every-time we open terminal or instance of terminal our `dotfiles` are loaded. So `.bash_profile` is loaded respectively and `export` that we appended above is run & thus a our global `$PATH` gets updated and we get all the commands inside `/usr/local/mysql/bin`.

P.s.

if you are not running first command export directly but just running second in order to persist it? Than for current running instance of terminal you have to,

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

This tells our terminal to reload that particular file.

Comment: For zsh, it should be in the "~/.zshrc" file and use command `source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: I had to run "source ~/.bash_profile" in order for this to work.  Even rebooting did not fix it for my

Answer (score 23):

That means /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql is not in the PATH variable..

Either execute /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql to get your mysql shell,

or type this in your terminal:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

to add that to your PATH variable so you can just run mysql without specifying the path

Comment: Thanks - I've just manually changed my path to `/usr/local/mysql/bin/` before I add it to the path.  I then typed `ls` and I can see all the mysql files, but when I type `mysql` I still get command not found?

Comment: the PATH variable and your current working directory are two different things.  $PATH, which is set by the line I gave you above, is where the system will look at when you just type a standalone command without the absolute/relative path.

Comment: when you changed you working directory to /usr/local/mysql/bin using `cd`, you have to invoke mysql by typing `./mysql` to let the system know to use mysql in the current directory, and not try to find it in one of the directory in your PATH variable

Comment: Thanks, things seem a lot clearer after your information.  I have just seen a a more complicated version of your line of code, but I am struggling to differentiate between your code and whats going on here: `echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin' >> ~/.bash_profile` Then he uses the `cat` command to open it.  All's I can see so far is that an invisible file has been created in the home directory.

Answer (score 8):

for me the following commands worked:

```
$ brew install mysql

$ brew services start mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just modified the `.bash_profile` by adding the MySQL `$PATH` as the following:
`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin`.

I did the following:

1- Open Terminal then `$ nano .bash_profile` or `$ vim .bash_profile`

2- Add the following PATH code to the `.bash_profile`

```
# Set architecture flags
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
# Ensure user-installed binaries take precedence
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
# Load .bashrc if it exists
test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

3- Save the file.

4- Refresh Terminal using `$ source ~/.bash_profile`

5- To verify, type in Terminal `$ mysql --version`

6- It should print the output something like this:

`$ mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for macos10.12 (x86_64)`

The Terminal is now configured to read the MySQL commands from `$PATH` which is placed in the `.bash_profile` .

Answer (score 0):

modify your bash profile as follows 
<>$vim ~/.bash_profile 
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
Once its saved you can type in mysql to bring mysql prompt in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a symlink to your mysql installation if it is not the most recent version of mysql.

```
$ brew link --force mysql@5.6
```

[see this post by Alex Todd](https://medium.com/@at0dd/install-mysql-5-7-on-mac-os-mojave-cd07ec936034)