# mysql command is not found in macOS

Tags: mysql, macos

I have installed MySQL with *.dmg* installation file according to the official page. But it returns `command not found: mysql` when I execute `mysql` command.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: This is similar to - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554818/using-mysql-in-the-command-line-in-osx-command-not-found or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577374/mysql-command-not-found-in-os-x-10-7)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The documentation for MySQL says:

> When installing using the package installer, the files are installed into a directory within /usr/local matching the name of the installation version and platform. For example, the installer file mysql-5.7.29-osx10.13-x86_64.dmg installs MySQL into /usr/local/mysql-5.7.29-osx10.13-x86_64/.

Once you verify that there is a bin folder in this directory, you have to make sure that the terminal looks for the MySQL command there. This can be done by executing the following command:

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/<my-path>/bin`

Comment: why do you have double slash?

Comment: That is a typo. It should be a single slash.

Comment: hello,  i found my path to my mysql, it's "/usr/local/mysql-8.0.27-macos11-arm64/bin", i am in my zshrc too, but i don't know how to put "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/<my-path>/bin" in to zshrc. How do i specify this path is for mysql? and where to put?

Answer (score 7):

Adding the following line to **.bash_profile** worked for me:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

Then either restart the terminal or to apply the changes to an existing session, run:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 2):

If you had installed mysql@5.7 using brew:

paste/type below command in terminal:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

then paste/type:

```
mysql -u root
```

boom!!!!

reason: brew files are installed in usr/local/opt

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you have not upgraded your OS and wants to access mysql

```
instead of    ->   mysql -u root -p
use           ->   /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: I think the idea is to use `mysql` instead of the full path for easy of use

Comment: For those who want to use `mysql`, edit your shell profile, if you're using Bash, this file is usually either ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bashrc, or ~/.profile. If you're using Zsh, it's likely ~/.zshrc. Add this line: `export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"`, restart the terminal and try `mysql -u root -p`