# MySQL command is not found in M1 Mac

Tags: mysql, zsh, apple-m1, zshrc

as titled, my question is in my m1 Mac terminal, after successfully installing MySQL from the official page, I enter the mysql command, but it returns command not found.

I googled alot, and this is one of the solution i found:[mysql command is not found in macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59025625/mysql-command-is-not-found-in-macos)

Per the instruction of the page, I found my path to my mysql already, it's `/usr/local/mysql-8.0.27-macos11-arm64/bin`,
I am now in my zshrc too, but i don't know how to put `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/<my-path>/bin` in to zshrc.

While there are so many lines of different settings in it, how do i specify this path is for mysql?
and where to put?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 4):

If not you using homebrew and have a manual installation of mysql:

```
vi ~/.zshrc
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql-8.0.28-macos11-x86_64/bin/
source ~/.zshrc
```

**note: replace `/mysql-8.0.28-maos11-x86_64/` with whichever version of mysql is installed.**

Answer (score 1):

Since `PATH`  is already exported (try a `printenv PATH` to see), you don't need to export it, but only extend it.

Hence, you can do in your .zshrc a

```
path+=/usr/local/mysql-8.0.27-macos11-arm64/bin
```

BTW, I would also do a

```
typeset -aU path
```

(if it is not there already), to ensure that you don't have duplicate entries in your PATH/path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does this "typeset -aU path" has to be in the front of, or behind the  "path+=/usr/local/mysql-8.0.27-macos11-arm64/bin" ?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but when i tried "mysql -u root -p", it still returns "zsh: command not found: mysql"

Comment: @EnzoY : AFIK, the position of the `typeset` does not matter, but the PATH is of course not cleaned for duplicates until zsh encounters this declaration.

Comment: @EnzoY : If it does not work, it means that your path statement has not been processed. Check the PATH and post it here. You can create a new zsh subshell with `zsh -x` and analyze the trace to see what's going on.