# Cannot find MySQL when trying to load a database

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to load a database into MySQL. I'm on a Mac, and I can see the MySQL server running in the system preferences. Also, when I issue the shell command `mysql` I'm entered into the interactive mode of mysql. However, when I try to load a database from the shell:

```
mysql -f --user root --password mypassword < database.sql
```

it gives me back `zsh: command not found: mysql`. Putting `sudo` in front does not make a difference. How can this be?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195418/cant-access-mysql-from-command-line-mac

Comment: check your path to see it it has mysql

Comment: Putting it in the path seems to work. But why can it find it when I just run `mysql`, but not when I attach the other flags?