# How to connect to MySQL database on server via Terminal on Macbook?

Tags: mysql, terminal

Is there a way to connect to my MySQL database and do something on tables via terminal?

Comment: Yes, there is the command line client, conveniently called `mysql`.

Comment: yes, `mysql: command not found`, how to install this?

Comment: Probably a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195418/cant-access-mysql-from-command-line-mac or several others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In your terminal start the mysql prompt using

```
mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name
```

Where *db_name* is the name of your database and user_name and password are your username and password.

You can then run SQL statements/queries from `.sql` files

```
mysql db_name < script.sql > output.tab
```

Where *db_name* is your database name, *script.sql* is a file containing your script, and *output.tab* (optional) is a file in which to dump the output of the query

You then simply place an SQL query in a file and run it.

---

If you get the error `mysql: command not found`, this is because the `mysql` executable cannot be found in your system PATH. If so, you need to run the following command to add the mySQL folder to the PATH, so that OS X knows to look there for the executable

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Where /usr/local/mysql is the location of your mysql installation.

You can add this to your `.bash_profile` file (located at `~\.bash_profile`, or you can create it) in order to have it run every time you start a new terminal. Otherwise you'll have to enter it manually before using the `mysql` command

Once you've entered this command (or added it to .bash_profile) you can use the mysql command as above

Alternately navigate to `/usr/local/mysql/bin` (or the location of your mysql install) and use the command

```
./mysql command
```

Instead of

```
mysql command
```

As above (where *command* is the command described in the first half of this post). This runs the `mysql` binary directly, rather than searching for it in the PATH

Comment: I've just updated the post (as you posted that comment) to address that issue :)

Comment: How do I know that mysql is installed on my macbook?

Comment: Well that's an entirely different question, and quite a long way from the scope of this one.... have you actually installed it? You can hardly expect it to work if it isn't there.

Comment: I never installed such thing. Is there a some tutorial how to install this?

Comment: Yes, many.... Google is probably your friend here. Do you want to access MySQL running on the MacBook, though, or do you want to connect to a DIFFERENT MySQL server from the Mac's command line?