# How to get a database up and running with php artisan for Laravel 5.x but I get this error when I check to see if I have MySQL running

Tags: php, mysql

```
zsh: command not found: mysql
```

I have exhausted the forums that provide suggestions and nothing is working and most talk about bash_profile, but this is an issue in my zsh environment.

It seems like it is definitely a path problem, this is what mines looks like:

```
ldco2016@DCortes-MacBook-Pro-3 ~/Projects/photogallery $ echo $PATH                                                                                                                                   [ruby-2.2.1]
/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/ldco2016/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/bin:/Users/ldco2016/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/ldco2016/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/ldco2016/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/ldco2016/.rvm/bin:/Users/ldco2016/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/ldco2016/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Also, when I go to /usr/local, there is no mysql folder in that directory:

```
ldco2016@DCortes-MacBook-Pro-3 /usr/local $ ll                                                                                                                                                        [ruby-2.2.1]
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    4 ldco2016  admin   136B Oct 13 14:01 Caskroom
drwxr-xr-x   96 ldco2016  admin   3.2K Nov 25 18:13 Cellar
drwxr-xr-x    3 ldco2016  admin   102B Aug  6 17:06 Frameworks
drwxr-xr-x   16 ldco2016  admin   544B Nov 25 18:12 Homebrew
drwxr-xr-x    6 root      wheel   204B Jun 28 08:18 MacGPG2
drwxr-xr-x@  11 ldco2016  staff   374B Aug  2 18:26 apache-maven
drwxrwxr-x  432 ldco2016  admin    14K Nov 25 18:13 bin
drwxr-xr-x   16 ldco2016  admin   544B Nov 25 18:13 etc
drwxr-xr-x   20 root      wheel   680B Oct 19 13:12 go
drwxr-xr-x  122 ldco2016  admin   4.1K Oct 26 20:11 include
drwxr-xr-x  282 ldco2016  admin   9.4K Oct 23 04:36 lib
drwxr-xr-x   96 ldco2016  admin   3.2K Nov 25 18:13 opt
drwxr-xr-x    4 ldco2016  admin   136B Oct  3 14:15 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   55 ldco2016  admin   1.8K Oct 26 20:11 share
drwx------@  46 ldco2016  staff   1.5K Aug  1 17:48 terraform
drwxr-xr-x   10 ldco2016  admin   340B Sep 21 18:01 var
```

These are the places where I have found mysql:

```
/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/mysql
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql
/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.0/darwin-2level/auto/DBD/mysql
/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.0/darwin-2level/DBD/mysql
/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql
/Applications/Zend Studio.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/com.zend.php.datatools.core_13.5.1.v20160705-1334/resources/drivers/mysql
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/mysql
/private/etc/paths.d/mysql
/private/var/mysql
/Users/ldco2016/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql
/Users/ldco2016/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql
/Users/ldco2016/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql
/Users/ldco2016/Documents/PycharmProjects/Survey/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/mysql
/Users/ldco2016/Documents/PycharmProjects/Survey/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql
/Users/ldco2016/ps-ansible/roles/mysql
/Users/ldco2016/workspace/todo/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql
/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.1.1.0/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/database/mysql
/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.1.1.0/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/extras/database/mysql
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/database/mysql
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/extras/database/mysql
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/mysql
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql
```

How can I proceed based on this evidence?

Comment: Windows? Linux? Give us a bit of a clue

Comment: Sounds like you don't have mysql installed at all.

Comment: Set your env variable for zsh. I mean set your mySQL path to be recognized by zsh environment. There are lots of tutorial on how to check and add env variables in zsh.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I am doing this on a Mac.

Comment: @aynber, how do I install mysql in the context of working with my Laravel app? I believe I have already added env variables in zsh.

Comment: If mysql is found in /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql, you just need to add it to the path. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195418/cant-access-mysql-from-command-line-mac , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577374/mysql-command-not-found-in-os-x-10-7). If it's not in /usr/local at all, then you need to [install the application itself](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/osx-installation-pkg.html).

Comment: @aynber, thank you, I went ahead and installed it because apparently I did not have it. Now when I do a mysql -u root, I get this error: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2), so I see this as progress.

Comment: Now that it's install, it probably needs to be started. Check your MAMP configuration, there should be an option to start it there.

Comment: @aynber, I installed it through homebrew and started the service via homebrew, but now when I tried php artisan migrate, I get this error: [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations)



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Sounds like it's the incorrect password for root. You can try to reset it or make sure it's correct in your .env file.

Comment: @aynber, when I hit php artisan migrate, I got a migration table created successfully, although those tables came with the installation of Laravel and were not created by me.

Comment: @aynber go ahead and post your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use mysql, you first need to install the [server itself](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/osx-installation-pkg.html), then add it to the PATH. Once it's installed and running, make sure that the correct credentials are in your `.env` file.